# How to add template to cordova project

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

Please I am newbie to Cordova technology. I am creating a project. and I don't know some CSS3 and Javascript frameworks to design it. 
Please if you can suggest me some of existing framewoks, or how to add template to my project.

Thank you for any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

There are two options which I suggest you,

**First** using `HTML frameworks` for building ios & android apps, like : [framework7](https://framework7.io/) and [jQuerymobile](https://jquerymobile.com/)
(of course by using these frameworks still you need to code html but in a more standard way and with less afford)

**Second** is using frameworks which have cordova engine inside them and provide you templates, like : [ionic](https://ionicframework.com/) which has a marketplace for its [templates](https://market.ionic.io/themes)

Comment: thanks a lot for answering my issue. How to Cordova and framework7 fit together i didn't find so much tutorial to work wih

Comment: @Aissam it's like including other resource files into your project, use sample codes inside your index.html and include other resource, you should know about how to code js and include other resources when you are using framework7 like other frameworks. Take a look at jquery mobile tutorial on w3schools that could help. And if this post helped you mark it as answer.